# Python search through file and un-escape unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode

I have a file that has random unicode characters in it and I would like to un-escape them. For example, `\uE0001` would become `uE0001` and `\uFEFF` would become `uFEFF`. So far, I have:

```py
with open(path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    s = f.read()
    s = s.replace("\\u", "u")
with open(fpath, "w"):
    f.write(s)
```

But that gives the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Either I did something wrong when replacing so there are still unicode characters, or python is still trying to encode it. What did I do wrong here, and how can I get a working program?

Comment: Show the file. Are you sure it's not JSON serialized?

Comment: Did you try `with open(path, encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:`?

Comment: @JosefZ `utf-8-sig` seemed to work! Thank you!